# AS3 Many tweening problems

Tags: actionscript-3, tween

I am having huge problems with AS3 and the tweening class. It just stops for no apparent reason...

My code is a menu of side panels that slide in-and-out when the user clicks the tabs.

It looks as follows:

```
var mainContent1X:Tween = new Tween(MainContent1, "x", Strong.easeOut, MainContent1.x, 325, 1, true);
var MainContent2X:Tween = new Tween(MainContent2, "x", Strong.easeOut, MainContent2.x, 1750, 1, true);
var mainContent3X:Tween = new Tween(MainContent3, "x", Strong.easeOut, MainContent3.x, 1750, 1, true);
var MainContent4X:Tween = new Tween(MainContent4, "x", Strong.easeOut, MainContent4.x, 1750, 1, true);
var mainContent5X:Tween = new Tween(MainContent5, "x", Strong.easeOut, MainContent5.x, 1750, 1, true);
var MainContent6X:Tween = new Tween(MainContent6, "x", Strong.easeOut, MainContent6.x, 1750, 1, true);
```

It just stops for no reason at all like the code isn't being executed. Sometimes only one tween happens and the others don't. Sometimes it works the way I want it to!!! I can't figure out why this is happening, I am relatively new to AS3, I'll appreciate any help.

Regards
Luben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume its a lifetime problem of your variables. If your tween variables are only in local scope of a function, at the end of that function they are lost and so your Tweens.

Make them class variables or even better, use [Tweener](http://code.google.com/p/tweener/).

Comment: Along with tweener I've enjoyed using [TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Daniel,

I declared the variables outside the function and all is fine. It seems that the garbage collector was clearing them at the wrong time. The code looks as follows now:

var mainContent1X:Tween;

function name() {
mainContent1X = new Tween(MainContent1, "x", Strong.easeOut, MainContent1.x, 325, 1, true);
...
}

I'll look into Tweener/TweenMax although I'm hesitant about using 3rd party software.

Thanks again,
Luben